# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'hello'

Tags: python, flask, pip, conda, environment

I did something really bad. I don't know what I did. I created a test project with `hello.py` where I did some mistake when running with some command. Now, I have deleted that and back to the real project, and I got the following error:

> File "/home/bhojendra/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 240, in locate_app
> **import**(module_name)
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'hello'

I don't have even the word `hello` anywhere in the project.

I have removed all pycaches from the project, cleaned the conda `conda clean -a`,  removed `myenv` environment and removed pip cache directory. Then, I re-created the environment and and re-installed the requirements and when launching the project with `flask run`, it throws that error again. Not sure what's happening.

It might be the issue with flask cache, I don't know how to overcome this issue.

Comment: did you set `hello.py` as your FLASK_APP, and is your directory name `flask`?

Comment: @AS11 Ah, thanks. I just remember it now. I had exported FLASK_APP. What could be the solution?

Comment: you just have to export the `FLASK_APP` as your new app name,

Comment: why not remove export? I think you should provide an answer which will help future visitors, you caught the exact culprit with the issue.

Comment: when setting a flask app, you have to `export` if you are using OSX (an apple machine), and `set` if you are using Windows

Comment: Yes, it works with OSX, Linux and anything with Unix Bash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your environment, you likely left your `FLASK_APP` set to the file `hello`, so it was trying to run that, although it doesn't exist. You just have to export or set your flask app based on what machine you are using.

Unix Bash (Linux, Mac, etc.):

```
$ export FLASK_APP=hello
$ flask run
```

Windows CMD:

```
> set FLASK_APP=hello
> flask run
```

Windows PowerShell:

```
> $env:FLASK_APP = "hello"
> flask run
```

---

You could also unset the export:

```
unset FLASK_APP
```

And then set the flask app